# I can't get calculator results to display with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, calculator

I'm using Foundation to create sliders for a Mortgage calculator and I have each slider connected to jQuery code but the results doesn't get display on the inputs i created

I added it to a jsfiddle to see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/to0namiSB/Ae5Y4/42/

And code is down below:

```
    <!-- Start of Mortgage Payment Calculator -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-12 large-centered columns ">
              <form>
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Mortgage Payment Calculator</legend>
                  <div class="row">
                      <h6 class="subheader">Use our loan calculator to help you determine the loan financing amount and payment options that are best for you.</h6>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                     <!-- This is the Loan Amount slider -->
                     <h6 class="subheader">Loan Amount:</h6>
                       <div class="range-slider round " data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput5; start: 1; end: 1000000;">
                          <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
                          <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
                          <input type="hidden">
                       </div>

                    <!-- The input where the user can input an number -->
                    <div class="small-4 large-2 columns right">
                      <input type="number" id="sliderOutput5">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                  <label>Years:</label>
                    <div class="range-slider round " data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3; start: 1; end: 60;">
                      <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
                      <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
                      <input type="hidden" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-4 large-2 columns right">
                      <input type="number" id="sliderOutput3">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <!-- This is the Interest slider -->
                    <h6 class="subheader">Interest:</h6>
                    <div class="range-slider round " data-slider data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput4;">
                      <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
                      <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
                      <input type="hidden">
                    </div>

                    <!-- The input where the user can input an number -->
                    <div class="small-4 large-2 columns right">
                      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" id="sliderOutput4">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row">

                     <input type=button id="btnPostJob" class="button right" value="Calculate"></input>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row">
                    <label>Approximate Payments:</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
<label>Monthly payment: $ <span class="output" id="payment"></span></label>

 <label>Total payment: $ <span class="output" id="total"></span></label>

<label>Total interest: $ <span class="output" id="totalinterest"></span></label>
                  </div>
                  </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

<!-- End of Mortgage Payment Calculator -->
```

the jQuery part

```
$(document).foundation();


      function doSum() {
        var amount = $("#sliderOutput5");
        var apr = $("#sliderOutput4");
        var years = $("#sliderOutput3");
        var payment = $("#payment");
        var total = $("#total");
        var totalinterest = $("#totalinterest");

        var principal = parseFloat($(amount).val());
        var interest = parseFloat($(apr).val()) / 100 / 12;
        var payments = parseFloat($(years).val()) * 12;

        var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
         var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);


        document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = monthly.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (monthly * payments).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById(totalinterest).innerHTML = ((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2);


 $("#payment, #total, #totalinterest").click(doSum);

};
```

EDIT: fixed the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues I see here:

1. The click event handler needs to be outside of the `dosum` function.
2. When you get the total interest element, 'totalinterest' needs to be in quotes, i.e. `document.getElementById('totalinterest')`, although it looks like you already fixed that in your jsfiddle.
3. Assuming you want the calculations to appear when you click "Calculate", you need to attach to the click handler to that element instead of the payment element, i.e. use `$("#btnPostJob").click(doSum);` instead of `$("#payment").click(doSum);`

Comment: question now it doesn't work when I add it to an external file.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean adding the script as an external file. I'm also guessing you are adding the script tag in the `<head>` tag. If that's the case, the reason it's not working is that the script is trying to attach the event handler to the `$("#btnPostJob")` before it's loaded. Try either putting the script tag at the bottom of the `<body>` tag or wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this for an alternative solution. plnkr.co/edit/hNg2gOTHa7ig2hPsrmZ8?p=preview